# What is a periodic module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

I've been reading the text

["THE THEORY OF COMMUTATIVE FORMAL GROUPS OVER FIELDS OF FINITE
CHARACTERISTIC"](http://stacky.net/posted/manin.pdf)

by Manin.

On page 26, proposition 2.1, the author mentions the notion of a periodic module, but as far as I can tell, does not define this anywhere. Could someone tell me what this means?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you heard of the term periodic group? It is synonymous with torsion group: each element has finite order.

Comment: Do you mean to say that this notion is similar to that of a torsion module? It seemed like the definition given in the answer below was similar but different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the definition see, for example, the introduction [here](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0022404977900573/1-s2.0-0022404977900573-main.pdf?_tid=aeca0bc4-ab38-11e5-bb39-00000aacb35d&acdnat=1451069744_dc4f05ed3f2b460c45a4c9c4f0e716ab). If the definition with syzygy here is not what you want, then it may be easier to understand some properties of periodic modules. For example, every periodic module over a principal ideal ring is a direct sum of cyclic modules.

Comment: Thanks! This is much appreciated, though I'm surprised I've never seen this defined before.  It just goes to show, there's always more commutative algebra out there.